# How to add additionalIcons to the tile in a Band

Tags: microsoft-band

I am developing Microsoft Band2 Apps, I want to add Additional icons to my app tile in a band, like setting tile in Band2. I followed the below code to add Additional icons to the tile

```
                    Guid pageguid = Guid.NewGuid();


                    var panel = new ScrollFlowPanel
                    {
                        Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 260, 128),
                    };
                    panel.Elements.Add(new FlowPanel
                    {
                        Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 32, 32),
                        HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Band.Tiles.Pages.HorizontalAlignment.Center,

                  });
                    panel.Elements.Add(new Icon
                    {
                        HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Band.Tiles.Pages.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                        Rect= new PageRect(0, 0, 32, 32),
                        ColorSource= ElementColorSource.BandHighlight,
                    });


                    var layout = new PageLayout(panel);
                    BandTile tile = new BandTile(tileGuid)
                    {
                        Name = "EmergencyHelp ",
                        TileIcon = await LoadIcon("ms-appx:///Assets/User that is member of security group.png"),
                        SmallIcon = await LoadIcon("ms-appx:///Assets/User that is member of security groupSmall.png"),


                    };
                    int firstIconIndex = tile.AdditionalIcons.Count + 2; // First 2 are used by the Tile itself
                    tile.AdditionalIcons.Add(await LoadIconMethod(AdjustUriMethod("ms-appx:///Assets/User that is member of security groupSmall.png")));
                    pageLayoutData.ById<IconData>(3).IconIndex = (ushort)(firstIconIndex + 0);
                    tile.PageLayouts.Add(layout);
                    if (tile.TileId != null)
                    {
                        await client.TileManager.RemoveTileAsync(tile.TileId);
                    }

                    await client.TileManager.AddTileAsync(tile);
                    await client.TileManager.SetPagesAsync(
                   tileGuid,
                   new PageData(pageguid, 0, new TextButtonData(1, "Emergency")));
```

I am getting the exception as shown in below figure,

[image]

Comment: You will need to describe the problem you've actually encountered.  Does the code produce an error?  Is it just not what you expected to see on the Band?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Just now I updated the post and added the exception.

Comment: It would help if you added the stack trace from the exception.  From the image, it would seem as if the error is coming from the call to your `LoadIconMethod()`, which isn't shown.  You need to verify that the icon is actually being loaded properly.